# Hiding Actionbar before fragment transaction (Android)

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar

My application contains an activity with several fragments. The activity displays the ActionBar by default. However, there are several fragments, displayed in order, where the ActionBar should not show. For these fragments, I hide the ActionBar in the onCreate code with `getActivity().getActionBar().hide();` . However, each time one of these fragments are loaded, the ActionBar flashes on the screen momentarily before disappearing.

How can I make the actionbar disappear before the fragments are displayed on the screen? For reference, below is the code I use for transactions between the fragments:

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment);
    transaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
```

Comment: What if you hide before committing the transaction?

Comment: Why can't you do the hiding within the activity?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest two ways to solve this.

1. Reconsider your activity-fragment relation, should it be split into different activities, i.e. some activities with action bar, some without action bar.
2. Use toolbar, and remove all default actionbar, assign the toolbar to your fragments which need it instead of the activity. Be reminded that you are not using setSupportActionBar() as this is not part of the activity layout.

Comment: A bit more detail on how to achieve number 2 would be much appreciated.